# Create a filled.contour plot with time (POSIXct) on x axis

Tags: r

I want to make a plot with time on x axis, depth on y axis and temperature as z values.
I converted time into the posixct format:

```
DateTime<-as.character.Date(Rohdaten$Datum..UTC.)
CompleteDate <- as.POSIXct(DateTime, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC")
```

These are the depths:

```
Tiefen <- c(1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20.5)
```

And my temperature values are in a matrix:

```
Temp <- as.matrix(data.frame(Daten$D1.1m, Daten$D1.3m, Daten$D1.5m, Daten$D1.10m, Daten$D1.15m, Daten$D1.20.5m))
Temp2 <- matrix(Temp, ncol=ncol(Temp), dimnames = NULL)
```

I use this code to make the plot:

```
filled.contour(CompleteDate,Tiefen,Temp2)
```

But I get an error message:

```
Error in filled.contour(CompleteDate, Tiefen, Temp2) : 
ansteigende 'x' und 'y' Werte erwartet
```

This error says that filled.contour expects ascending x and y values.
When I take

```
Time <- c(1:3405)
```

Instead of the time in the posixct format the plot is created:

[Plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrrWT.png)

What can I do to take my actual dates and times as the x axis?

Here are my CompleteDates in the POSIXct format:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0h643u7lpzq9mu/CompleteDate.txt?dl=0

Comment: Use timestamps as values for time and the POSIXct format for the axis labels afterwards. I cannot tell for sure how you data looks like so this is vague. Try `as.numeric(CompleteDate)`and use `axis()`afterwards.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer I used the 'as.numeric(CompleteDate)' and used this as x axis in the filled.contour but it still doesn't work. It gives the same eroor message as when I use the POSIXct Format for the x axis.

Comment: Sort the data by ascending dates then.

Comment: What I made:
`Time2 <- as.numeric(CompleteDate)` and then `Time3 <- sort(Time2, decreasing = FALSE)` then `filled.contour(Time3,Tiefen,Temp2)` but I still get the same error message.

Comment: Just provide a snapshot of your data using `dput()` please.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer I provided a link in the end of the question.
I was thinking about another solution: I could make the plot with my integer x axis and then use my Dates in the posixct Format for labelling the x axis after plotting. But it didnt' work...

Comment: So for each of those dates you have 5 temperature values for different depths, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using only a snapshot of your Dates and fictional Temperatures:

```
DateTime <- structure(c(1472209200, 1472212800, 1472216400, 1472220000, 1472223600, 
                        1472227200, 1472230800, 1472234400, 1472238000, 1472241600, 1472245200, 
                        1472248800, 1472252400, 1472256000, 1472259600, 1472263200, 1472266800, 
                        1472270400, 1472274000, 1472277600, 1472281200, 1472284800, 1472288400, 
                        1472292000, 1472295600, 1472299200, 1472302800, 1472306400, 1472310000, 
                        1472313600, 1472317200, 1472320800, 1472324400, 1472328000, 1472331600
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")

Tiefen <- c(1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20.5)

# now create fictive temperatures
df   <- expand.grid("Date" = DateTime, "Tiefen" = Tiefen)
df   <- df %>% group_by(Tiefen) %>% mutate(Temp = runif(n(), 15 - Tiefen/2, 27 - Tiefen)) %>% ungroup()
Temp <- matrix(df$Temp, nrow = length(DateTime))


inMeter <- function(x) {
  paste0(x, "m")
}

inCelsius <- function(x) {
  paste0(x, "°C")
}

filled.contour(x = as.numeric(DateTime), y = Tiefen, z = Temp,  
               plot.axes = { 
                 axis(1, labels = DateTime, at = as.numeric(DateTime), las = 2, cex.axis = 0.5) 
                 axis(2, at = Tiefen, labels = inMeter(Tiefen), cex.axis = 1) 
               },
               key.axes = {
                 axis(4, at = pretty(Temp), labels = inCelsius(pretty(Temp))) 
               })
```

Notes:

- We supply the unix timestamp (by using `as.numeric()`) as x values for the plot.
- We plot a new axis using the original POSIXct strings. I made them smaller. Since you have a lot of dates, make sure the plot is not overloaded.
- The `z` values (`Temp`) are supplied as a matrix which has as many rows as we have x values.
- I added two functions in order two plot the y axis for both the plot and the key with corresponding units.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Do you know how I could Show only the months on my x-axis? I tried something like this:
`# wenn in Plot xaxt = "n" (keine X-Achse), dann kann so X-Achse selber gemacht werden:
daterange=c(as.numeric(min(CompleteDate[1:4000])), as.numeric(max(CompleteDate[1:4000])))
axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(daterange[1], daterange[2], by="month"), format="%b")`
But it didn't work inside the contour.plot. It worked in a normal plot.

Comment: Use `lubridate::month(DateTime)` for the axis labels.

Comment: this could work. But how can I show the Name of the month only once per month and not at every timestep? When I use `axis(1, labels = month(CompleteDate, label = T), at = as.numeric(CompleteDate), las = 2, cex.axis = 0.5)` the month will be the same for a lot of timesteps but I want to show every month only once so that I don't get a overloaded x-axis.

Comment: Try `timespan <- range(DateTime);
start    <- as.POSIXct(format(timespan[1], "%Y-%m-01"));
end      <- as.POSIXct(format(timespan[2], "%Y-%m-01"));
xLabels  <- seq(start, end, "1 month")`. Then `labels = xLabels` and `at = as.numeric(xLabels)`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!
Do you know how I could Show the month and the year, like for example Sep-17? Is there a function in the lubridate package?